# Passing a function down to child component not working

Tags: reactjs

first time asking something here so pardon if it's not in the right template.
I'm trying to pass down a function that I created on App.js to an input component, so on a button click it changes the state in the App component and it returns errors.

App.jsx

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Todos from "./components/Todos";
import Input from "./components/Input";

function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  let startingId = 1;

  function addTodo(title) {
    if (title) {
      setTodos((prev) =>
        prev.push({
          id: startingId++,
          title: title,
          createdAt: new Date().toLocaleTimeString(),
          isComplete: false,
        })
      );
    }
    return;
  }
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Input addTodo={addTodo} />
      <Todos todos={todos} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Input.jsx

```
import { useState } from "react";

function Input({ addTodo }) {
  const [todoInp, setTodoInp] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="input mt-4 mb-5">
      <div className="input-group mb-3 container-lg">
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Recipient's username"
          aria-label="Recipient's username"
          aria-describedby="button-addon2"
          value={todoInp}
          onInput={(e) => setTodoInp(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button
          className="btn btn-outline-primary"
          type="button"
          id="button-addon2"
          onClick={addTodo(todoInp)}
        >
          Add Todo
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Input;
```

**Small update:
Thanks for the quick response guys, I've been battling with this assignment for quite some time and finally finished it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are possible problems with your code.

[CODESANDBOX DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-elgamal-zdv6i0?file=/src/App.js)

use `onChange` instead of `onInput` as

```
onChange={ ( e ) => setTodoInp( e.target.value ) }
```

You have to pass a function to `onClick`, you are invoking it. So it should be as:

```
onClick={ () => addTodo( todoInp ) }
```

You have to return a new array so that react comes to know when to re-render the component. If you pass same array then react won't re-render it.

```
  setTodos( ( prev ) => ( [
    ...prev,
    {
      id: startingId++,
      title: title,
      createdAt: new Date().toLocaleTimeString(),
      isComplete: false,
    }
  ] ) );
```

> You should pass a unique id to each element in an array when you use `map` in JSX.

You can create a new state as

```
const [startingId, setstartingId] = useState(0);
```

and increment it as:

```
setTodos((prev) => [
    ...prev,
    {
        id: startingId + 1,
        title: title,
        createdAt: new Date().toLocaleTimeString(),
        isComplete: false,
    },
]);
setstartingId((id) => id + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass the `addTodo` function to `onClick` with parentheses because you are actually passing `addTodo` returned result. But in your case, you also need to pass `title` to the `addTodo` function so, you need to give `onClick` a callback function.

```js
<button
  className="btn btn-outline-primary"
  type="button"
  id="button-addon2"
  onClick={() => addTodo(todoInp)}
>
  Add Todo
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

everything you did is correct except for the fact that you didn't pass the title parameter in the "Input" component,thus title is undefined and the if condition is false and the state is not getting updated,please pass the title in the addTodo() function call in "Input" component